# Angular fire ng-click on row but not on href

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, events, angularjs-ng-click

I've made a page with bootstrap, and i would like to have an action when the user clicks on the row. This is easy, I put `ng-click` on the `div` that is the row.

However, inside the row elements I've a link, and I would like to avoid the firing of the `ng-click` when the user clicks on the link (in that case it should open the url of the link)

this is a [picture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/583aa53hmsdmh8q/Screenshot%202015-05-29%2017.54.31.png?dl=0) of the row. Bascially if the use clicks anywhere except the link simbol it should filre the ng-click, if it clicks on the link simbol it should open the url.

is this possible?

PS: I tried to put `ng-click` on each item except the href element, but the href element is inside a column within other things, and if I don't put the `ng-click` on the column it will not fire if the use clicks on the empty space of the column.

```
<div class="col-sm-8" >
   <a href="{{club.url}}" ><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a> |
   <span class="h5 small">{{club.description}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: can u share on jsfidder ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$event.stopPropagation()` on `ng-click` of anchor tag to bubble up event.

**Markup**

```
<div class="col-sm-8" ng-click="myMethod()">
    <a href="{{club.url}}" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a> |
</div>
```

Comment: Is the $event.preventDefault(); on the container necessary?

Comment: Thats my bad..it is not needed..if `div` is wrapped with anchor then that's work

Answer (score 2):

You have to stop the event propagation from anchor to its parent div which has the click event handler.

```
<div class="col-sm-8" ng-click="onRowClick()">
   <a href="{{club.url}}" ng-click="onLinkClick($event)" ><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a> |
   <span class="h5 small">{{club.description}}</span>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.onLinkClick = function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: The other response is "shorter", still this is also correct. But i chosed the other one.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();"` to your anchor tag

```
<a href="{{club.url}}" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
```

Comment: You missed a comma after the ()

Comment: Why would it need a comma? You mean semicolon?